# Access email id and phone number from Facebook Graph api in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am integrating Facebook login and access the data of user, I have done that, but there was a problem - it is not retuning the email id or contact number.

```
 private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {
            StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");


            userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", 
                user.getName()));


            userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", 
                user.getBirthday()));


            userInfo.append(String.format("Email: %s\n\n", 
                    user.getUsername()));

            userInfo.append(String.format("Gender: %s\n\n", 
                    user.getProperty("gender")));

            userInfo.append(String.format("Iddddddd: %s\n\n", 
                    user.getId()));

            userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", 
                user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));


            userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", 
                user.getProperty("locale")));

            System.out.println("User info"+userInfo);




        }
```

user info return all data but not email id or contact number

Comment: What's the code that you used to integrate the plugin ? post it here . Also what is the error that you are getting. Post the error stack trace .

Comment: `it is not retuning the email id or contact number` -- what are you referring to by "**it**"? Some method? Some variable? Share your code that is not working

Comment: `user.getUsername()` will just get the user name and not the email id.

Comment: yes but i am asking how to get email address and contact number there is no property for email or contact

Comment: The only way to get the users e-mail address is to request extended permissions on the email field. The user must allow you to see this and you cannot get the e-mail addresses of the users friends.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

You can do this if you are using Facebook connect by passing scope=email in the get string of your call to the Auth Dialog.

Comment: thanks for that  i am going to do this

Comment: Look at my updated answer, it's a jsonish way of doing things and much easier .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first  thing's first :

```
 public static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"email"};

  String response=authenticatedFacebook.request("me");
  JSONObject obj = Util.parseJson(response);
   useremail=obj.getString("email");`
```

where authenticatedFacebook is Facebook object.

Util will  be available along with Facebook SDK. However, i think `util` might be depriciated, so you can always use : `user.getInnerJSONObject().getString("email");`

Ensure that you gave **Email permission** .

Comment: Is it possible to get phone number too?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal : I am not sure about that. Read about the API in Android developer's forum . You are bound to get some answers there .